# .ELF too big when adding two C++ files to ARM MCU project

Tags: c++, g++, embedded, atmel, sam

I'm trying to write some C++ code for a Atmel SAM3S1 microcontroller. I'm Using the ASF Library with the FreeRTOS library included. I wrote a simple and small C++ wrapper (3 .cpp files) so I can easily inherit it in my device classes.

The Atmel SAM ([datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/ATMEL_6500S-32-bit%20Cortex-M3%20Microcontroller_SAM3S_Summary-Datasheet.pdf)) has 64KB Flash and 16KB RAM which I think is more then enough. although when I start compiling I get the message:

```
section `.text' will not fit in region `rom'

/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: region `rom' overflowed by 13120 bytes
```

I use arm-none-eabi-g++ to compile and link everything.

When I clear the declared Class in Main.cpp the sizes are just fine so I think that is has something to do with C++.  Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
Test.elf  :
section              size         addr
.text              0x102c     0x400000
.ARM.exidx            0x8     0x40102c
.relocate           0x844   0x20000000
.bss                0x154   0x20000844
.stack             0x2000   0x20000998
.ARM.attributes      0x29          0x0
.comment             0x70          0x0
.debug_info        0x57d1          0x0
.debug_abbrev      0x1058          0x0
.debug_aranges      0x430          0x0
.debug_ranges       0xb00          0x0
.debug_macro       0xf50a          0x0
.debug_line        0x5024          0x0
.debug_str        0x46ec7          0x0
.debug_frame        0xe04          0x0
.debug_loc         0x31f1          0x0
Total             0x6a5a8


   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 0x1034   0x844  0x2154   14796    39cc Test.elf
```

These are my CPP files:

Main.cpp

```
#include <asf.h>
#include <MMA8652.h>

extern "C" { 
  extern void vApplicationStackOverflowHook(xTaskHandle *pxTask,
          signed char *pcTaskName) {

  }
}


int main(void) {
  const taskConfig_t AccelTaskConfig = { "AccelRx", 3, 100 };

  MMA8652 Accelero(AccelTaskConfig);



    return(0);
}
```

Task.h

```
//#ifndef TASK_H 
//#define TASK_H
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct {
    char *taskName;
    uint8_t priority;
    uint16_t stackSize;
} taskConfig_t;

class Task {

    private:

    public: 
    Task(char *taskName, uint8_t priority, uint16_t stackSize);
    ~Task();

    friend void run_helper(void *arg) {
        return static_cast<Task*>(arg)->run();
    }

    virtual void run(void) const = 0;

    protected:

};

//#endif
```

Task.cpp

```
#include <Task.h>
#include <asf.h>

void run_helper(void *arg);

Task::Task( char *taskName, 
            uint8_t priority, 
            uint16_t stackSize ) {

    // check for minimal stacksize
    if(stackSize < configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE) {
        stackSize = configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE;
    }

    // check priority val
    if(priority > configMAX_PRIORITIES) {
        priority = configMAX_PRIORITIES;
    }

    // create a new FreeRTOS task with func ptr to run() member
    xTaskCreate( &run_helper, (const signed char *) taskName,
     stackSize, (Task*)this, priority, NULL);
}
```

MMA8652.h

```
#ifndef MMA8652_H
#define MMA8652_H

#include <Task.h>

class MMA8652: public Task {

private:

public:
    void run(void) const;
    MMA8652(const taskConfig_t &tConfig);
    ~MMA8652(void);
};


#endif // MMA8652_H
```

MMA8652.cpp

```
#include <asf.h>
#include <MMA8652.h>

MMA8652::MMA8652(const taskConfig_t &tConfig) : 
        Task(tConfig.taskName, tConfig.priority, tConfig.stackSize) {



}

void MMA8652::run(void) const {

    pio_set_pin_high(TESTLED_GPIO);
    vTaskDelay(1000);
    pio_set_pin_low(TESTLED_GPIO);
    vTaskDelay(1000);
 }
```

linker_script.ld

```
    OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
SEARCH_DIR(.)

/* Memory Spaces Definitions */
MEMORY
{
    rom (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00400000, LENGTH = 0x00010000 /* Flash, 64K */
    ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00004000 /* sram, 16K */
}

/* The stack size used by the application. NOTE: you need to adjust  */
__stack_size__ = DEFINED(__stack_size__) ? __stack_size__ : 0x2000;
__ram_end__ = ORIGIN(ram) + LENGTH(ram) - 4;

/* Section Definitions */ 
SECTIONS 
{ 
    .text : 
    { 
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sfixed = .;
        KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.*))
        *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)        
        *(.glue_7t) *(.glue_7)                      
        *(.rodata .rodata* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)                                 
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)

        /* Support C constructors, and C destructors in both user code
           and the C library. This also provides support for C++ code. */
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.init))
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __preinit_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
        __preinit_array_end = .;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __init_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.init_array))
        __init_array_end = .;

        . = ALIGN(0x4);
        KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
        KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .ctors))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
        KEEP (*crtend.o(.ctors))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.fini))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __fini_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.fini_array))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        __fini_array_end = .;

        KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
        KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .dtors))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
        KEEP (*crtend.o(.dtors))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _efixed = .;            /* End of text section */
    } > rom

    /* .ARM.exidx is sorted, so has to go in its own output section.  */
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_start = .);
    .ARM.exidx :
    {
      *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    } > rom
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_end = .);

    . = ALIGN(4); 
    _etext = .;

    .relocate : AT (_etext)
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _srelocate = .;
        *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.*);
        *(.data .data.*);
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _erelocate = .;
    } > ram

    /* .bss section which is used for uninitialized data */ 
    .bss (NOLOAD) :
    { 
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sbss = . ;
        _szero = .;
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = . ;
        _ezero = .;
    } > ram

    /* stack section */
    .stack (NOLOAD):
    {
        . = ALIGN(8);
         _sstack = .;
        . = . + __stack_size__;
        . = ALIGN(8);
        _estack = .;
    } > ram

    . = ALIGN(4); 
    _end = . ; 
}
```

config.mk

```
# Path to top level ASF directory relative to this project directory.
PRJ_PATH = ASF

# Target CPU architecture: cortex-m3, cortex-m4
ARCH = cortex-m3

# Target part: none, sam3n4 or sam4l4aa
PART = sam3s1ab

# Application target name. Given with suffix .a for library and .elf for a
# standalone application.
TARGET_FLASH = $(PRJ_NAME).elf
TARGET_SRAM = $(PRJ_NAME).elf

# List of C source files.
CSRCS = \
    Main.cpp                          \
       lib/Task.cpp                                       \
       devices/MMA8652.cpp                                \
       sam/boards/Board/init.c                        \
       common/services/clock/sam3s/sysclk.c               \
       common/utils/interrupt/interrupt_sam_nvic.c        \
       common/utils/stdio/read.c                          \
       common/utils/stdio/write.c                         \
       sam/drivers/pio/pio.c                              \
       sam/drivers/pio/pio_handler.c                      \
       sam/drivers/pmc/pmc.c                              \
       sam/drivers/pmc/sleep.c                            \
       sam/utils/cmsis/sam3s/source/templates/exceptions.c \
       sam/utils/cmsis/sam3s/source/templates/gcc/startup_sam3s.c \
       sam/utils/cmsis/sam3s/source/templates/system_sam3s.c \
       sam/utils/syscalls/gcc/syscalls.c                  \
       thirdparty/freertos/freertos-7.0.0/source/croutine.c \
       thirdparty/freertos/freertos-7.0.0/source/list.c   \
       thirdparty/freertos/freertos-7.0.0/source/portable/gcc/sam/port.c \
       thirdparty/freertos/freertos-7.0.0/source/portable/memmang/heap_3.c \
       thirdparty/freertos/freertos-7.0.0/source/queue.c  \
       thirdparty/freertos/freertos-7.0.0/source/tasks.c  \
       thirdparty/freertos/freertos-7.0.0/source/timers.c

# List of assembler source files.
ASSRCS = 

# List of include paths.
INC_PATH = \
       ../lib/include                           \
       ../devices/include                                 \
       ../config                                \
       ../                                  \
       common/services/clock                              \
       common/boards                                   \
       common/services/gpio                               \
       common/services/ioport                             \
       common/utils                                       \
       sam/drivers/pio                                    \
       sam/drivers/pmc                                    \
       sam/utils                                          \
       sam/utils/cmsis/sam3s/include                      \
       sam/utils/cmsis/sam3s/source/templates             \
       sam/utils/header_files                             \
       sam/utils/preprocessor                             \
       thirdparty/CMSIS/Include                           \
       thirdparty/CMSIS/Lib/GCC                           \
       thirdparty/freertos/freertos-7.0.0/source/include  \
       thirdparty/freertos/freertos-7.0.0/source/portable/gcc/sam \

# Additional search paths for libraries.
LIB_PATH =  \
       thirdparty/CMSIS/Lib/GCC                          

# List of libraries to use during linking.
LIBS =                                                  

# Path relative to top level directory pointing to a linker script.
LINKER_SCRIPT_FLASH = sam/utils/linker_scripts/sam3s/sam3s1/gcc/flash.ld
LINKER_SCRIPT_SRAM  = sam/utils/linker_scripts/sam3s/sam3s1/gcc/sram.ld

# Project type parameter: all, sram or flash
PROJECT_TYPE        = flash

# Additional options for debugging. By default the common Makefile.in will
# add -g3.
DBGFLAGS = 

# Application optimization used during compilation and linking:
# -O0, -O1, -O2, -O3 or -Os
OPTIMIZATION = -O3

# Extra flags to use when archiving.
ARFLAGS = 

# Extra flags to use when assembling.
ASFLAGS = 

# Extra flags to use when compiling.
CFLAGS = 

# Extra flags to use when preprocessing.
#
# Preprocessor symbol definitions
#   To add a definition use the format "-D name[=definition]".
#   To cancel a definition use the format "-U name".
#
# The most relevant symbols to define for the preprocessor are:
#   BOARD      Target board in use, see boards/board.h for a list.
#   EXT_BOARD  Optional extension board in use, see boards/board.h for a list.
CPPFLAGS = \
       -D __FREERTOS__                                    \
       -D __SAM3S1B__                                     \
       -D BOARD=BOARD                 \
       -D printf=iprintf                                  \
       -D scanf=iscanf

# Extra flags to use when linking
LDFLAGS = \

# Pre- and post-build commands
PREBUILD_CMD = 
POSTBUILD_CMD =
```

Makefile.sam.in

```
include config.mk

# Tool to use to generate documentation from the source code
DOCGEN          ?= doxygen

# Look for source files relative to the top-level source directory
VPATH           := $(PRJ_PATH)

# Output target file
project_type    := $(PROJECT_TYPE)

# Output target file
ifeq ($(project_type),flash)
target          := $(TARGET_FLASH)
linker_script   := $(PRJ_PATH)/$(LINKER_SCRIPT_FLASH)
debug_script    := $(PRJ_PATH)/$(DEBUG_SCRIPT_FLASH)
else
target          := $(TARGET_SRAM)
linker_script   := $(PRJ_PATH)/$(LINKER_SCRIPT_SRAM)
debug_script    := $(PRJ_PATH)/$(DEBUG_SCRIPT_SRAM)
endif

# Output project name (target name minus suffix)
project         := $(basename $(target))

# Output target file (typically ELF or static library)
ifeq ($(suffix $(target)),.a)
target_type     := lib
else
ifeq ($(suffix $(target)),.elf)
target_type     := elf
else
$(error "Target type $(target_type) is not supported")
endif
endif

# Allow override of operating system detection. The user can add OS=Linux or
# OS=Windows on the command line to explicit set the host OS.
#
# This allows to work around broken uname utility on certain systems.
ifdef OS
  ifeq ($(strip $(OS)), Linux)
    os_type     := Linux
  endif
  ifeq ($(strip $(OS)), Windows)
    os_type     := windows32_64
  endif
endif

os_type         ?= $(strip $(shell uname))

ifeq ($(os_type),windows32)
os              := Windows
else
ifeq ($(os_type),windows64)
os              := Windows
else
ifeq ($(os_type),windows32_64)
os              ?= Windows
else
ifeq ($(os_type),)
os              := Windows
else
# Default to Linux style operating system. Both Cygwin and mingw are fully
# compatible (for this Makefile) with Linux.
os              := Linux
endif
endif
endif
endif

# Output documentation directory and configuration file.
docdir          := ../doxygen/html
doccfg          := ../doxygen/doxyfile.doxygen

CROSS           ?= arm-none-eabi-
AR              := $(CROSS)ar
AS              := $(CROSS)as
CC              := $(CROSS)gcc
CPP             := $(CROSS)gcc -E
CXX             := $(CROSS)g++
LD              := $(CROSS)g++
NM              := $(CROSS)nm
OBJCOPY         := $(CROSS)objcopy
OBJDUMP         := $(CROSS)objdump
SIZE            := $(CROSS)size
GDB             := $(CROSS)gdb

RM              := rm
ifeq ($(os),Windows)
RMDIR           := rmdir /S /Q
else
RMDIR           := rmdir -p --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
endif

# On Windows, we need to override the shell to force the use of cmd.exe
ifeq ($(os),Windows)
SHELL           := cmd
endif

# Strings for beautifying output
MSG_CLEAN_FILES         = "RM      *.o *.d"
MSG_CLEAN_DIRS          = "RMDIR   $(strip $(clean-dirs))"
MSG_CLEAN_DOC           = "RMDIR   $(docdir)"
MSG_MKDIR               = "MKDIR   $(dir $@)"

MSG_INFO                = "INFO    "
MSG_PREBUILD            = "PREBUILD  $(PREBUILD_CMD)"
MSG_POSTBUILD           = "POSTBUILD $(POSTBUILD_CMD)"

MSG_ARCHIVING           = "AR      $@"
MSG_ASSEMBLING          = "AS      $@"
MSG_BINARY_IMAGE        = "OBJCOPY $@"
MSG_COMPILING           = "CC      $@"
MSG_COMPILING_CXX       = "CXX     $@"
MSG_EXTENDED_LISTING    = "OBJDUMP $@"
MSG_IHEX_IMAGE          = "OBJCOPY $@"
MSG_LINKING             = "LN      $@"
MSG_PREPROCESSING       = "CPP     $@"
MSG_SIZE                = "SIZE    $@"
MSG_SYMBOL_TABLE        = "NM      $@"

MSG_GENERATING_DOC      = "DOXYGEN $(docdir)"

# Don't use make's built-in rules and variables
MAKEFLAGS       += -rR

# Don't print 'Entering directory ...'
MAKEFLAGS       += --no-print-directory

# Function for reversing the order of a list
reverse = $(if $(1),$(call reverse,$(wordlist 2,$(words $(1)),$(1)))) $(firstword $(1))

# Hide command output by default, but allow the user to override this
# by adding V=1 on the command line.
#
# This is inspired by the Kbuild system used by the Linux kernel.
ifdef V
  ifeq ("$(origin V)", "command line")
    VERBOSE = $(V)
  endif
endif
ifndef VERBOSE
  VERBOSE = 0
endif

ifeq ($(VERBOSE), 1)
  Q =
else
  Q = @
endif

arflags-gnu-y           := $(ARFLAGS)
asflags-gnu-y           := $(ASFLAGS)
cflags-gnu-y            := $(CFLAGS)
cxxflags-gnu-y          := $(CXXFLAGS)
cppflags-gnu-y          := $(CPPFLAGS)
cpuflags-gnu-y          :=
dbgflags-gnu-y          := $(DBGFLAGS)
libflags-gnu-y          := $(foreach LIB,$(LIBS),-l$(LIB))
ldflags-gnu-y           := $(LDFLAGS)
flashflags-gnu-y        :=
clean-files             :=
clean-dirs              :=

clean-files             += $(wildcard $(target) $(project).map)
clean-files             += $(wildcard $(project).hex $(project).bin)
clean-files             += $(wildcard $(project).lss $(project).sym)
clean-files             += $(wildcard $(build))

# Use pipes instead of temporary files for communication between processes
cflags-gnu-y    += -pipe
asflags-gnu-y   += -pipe
ldflags-gnu-y   += -pipe

# Archiver flags.
arflags-gnu-y   += rcs

# Always enable warnings. And be very careful about implicit
# declarations.
cflags-gnu-y    += -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes
cflags-gnu-y    += -Werror-implicit-function-declaration
cxxflags-gnu-y  += -Wall
# IAR doesn't allow arithmetic on void pointers, so warn about that.
cflags-gnu-y    += -Wpointer-arith
cxxflags-gnu-y  += -Wpointer-arith

# Preprocessor flags.
cppflags-gnu-y  += $(foreach INC,$(addprefix $(PRJ_PATH)/,$(INC_PATH)),-I$(INC))
asflags-gnu-y   += $(foreach INC,$(addprefix $(PRJ_PATH)/,$(INC_PATH)),'-Wa,-I$(INC)')

# CPU specific flags.
cpuflags-gnu-y  += -mcpu=$(ARCH) -mthumb -D=__$(PART)__

# Dependency file flags.
depflags        = -MD -MP -MQ $@

# Debug specific flags.
ifdef BUILD_DEBUG_LEVEL
dbgflags-gnu-y  += -g$(BUILD_DEBUG_LEVEL)
else
dbgflags-gnu-y  += -g3
endif

# Optimization specific flags.
ifdef BUILD_OPTIMIZATION
optflags-gnu-y  = -O$(BUILD_OPTIMIZATION)
else
optflags-gnu-y  = $(OPTIMIZATION)
endif

# Always preprocess assembler files.
asflags-gnu-y   += -x assembler-with-cpp
# Compile C files using the GNU99 standard.
cflags-gnu-y    += -std=gnu99
# Compile C++ files using the GNU++98 standard.
cxxflags-gnu-y  += -std=gnu++98

# Don't use strict aliasing (very common in embedded applications).
cflags-gnu-y    += -fno-strict-aliasing
cxxflags-gnu-y  += -fno-strict-aliasing

# Separate each function and data into its own separate section to allow
# garbage collection of unused sections.
cflags-gnu-y    += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
cxxflags-gnu-y  += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections

# Various cflags.
cflags-gnu-y += -Wchar-subscripts -Wcomment -Wformat=2 -Wimplicit-int
cflags-gnu-y += -Wmain -Wparentheses
cflags-gnu-y += -Wsequence-point -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wtrigraphs -Wunused
cflags-gnu-y += -Wuninitialized -Wunknown-pragmas -Wfloat-equal -Wundef
cflags-gnu-y += -Wshadow -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings
cflags-gnu-y += -Wsign-compare -Waggregate-return
cflags-gnu-y += -Wmissing-declarations
cflags-gnu-y += -Wformat -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-deprecated-declarations
cflags-gnu-y += -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wlong-long
cflags-gnu-y += -Wunreachable-code
cflags-gnu-y += -Wcast-align
cflags-gnu-y += --param max-inline-insns-single=500

# Garbage collect unreferred sections when linking.
ldflags-gnu-y   += -Wl,--gc-sections

# Use the linker script if provided by the project.
ifneq ($(strip $(linker_script)),)
ldflags-gnu-y   += -Wl,-T $(linker_script)
endif

# Output a link map file and a cross reference table
ldflags-gnu-y   += -Wl,-Map=$(project).map,--cref

# Add library search paths relative to the top level directory.
ldflags-gnu-y   += $(foreach _LIB_PATH,$(addprefix $(PRJ_PATH)/,$(LIB_PATH)),-L$(_LIB_PATH))

a_flags  = $(cpuflags-gnu-y) $(depflags) $(cppflags-gnu-y) $(asflags-gnu-y) -D__ASSEMBLY__
c_flags  = $(cpuflags-gnu-y) $(dbgflags-gnu-y) $(depflags) $(optflags-gnu-y) $(cppflags-gnu-y) $(cflags-gnu-y)
cxx_flags= $(cpuflags-gnu-y) $(dbgflags-gnu-y) $(depflags) $(optflags-gnu-y) $(cppflags-gnu-y) $(cxxflags-gnu-y)
l_flags  = -Wl,--entry=Reset_Handler -Wl,--cref $(cpuflags-gnu-y) $(optflags-gnu-y) $(ldflags-gnu-y)
ar_flags = $(arflags-gnu-y)

# Source files list and part informations must already be included before
# running this makefile

# If a custom build directory is specified, use it -- force trailing / in directory name.
ifdef BUILD_DIR
    build-dir       := $(dir $(BUILD_DIR))$(if $(notdir $(BUILD_DIR)),$(notdir $(BUILD_DIR))/)
else
    build-dir        =
endif

# Create object files list from source files list.
obj-y                   := $(addprefix $(build-dir), $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(CSRCS) $(ASSRCS))))
# Create dependency files list from source files list.
dep-files               := $(wildcard $(foreach f,$(obj-y),$(basename $(f)).d))

clean-files             += $(wildcard $(obj-y))
clean-files             += $(dep-files)

clean-dirs              += $(call reverse,$(sort $(wildcard $(dir $(obj-y)))))

# Default target.
.PHONY: all
ifeq ($(project_type),all)
all:
    $(MAKE) all PROJECT_TYPE=flash
    $(MAKE) all PROJECT_TYPE=sram
else
ifeq ($(target_type),lib)
all: $(target) $(project).lss $(project).sym
else
ifeq ($(target_type),elf)
all: prebuild $(target) $(project).lss $(project).sym $(project).hex $(project).bin postbuild
endif
endif
endif

prebuild:
ifneq ($(strip $(PREBUILD_CMD)),)
    @echo $(MSG_PREBUILD)
    $(Q)$(PREBUILD_CMD)
endif

postbuild:
ifneq ($(strip $(POSTBUILD_CMD)),)
    @echo $(MSG_POSTBUILD)
    $(Q)$(POSTBUILD_CMD)
endif

# Clean up the project.
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(if $(strip $(clean-files)),echo $(MSG_CLEAN_FILES))
    $(if $(strip $(clean-files)),$(Q)$(RM) $(clean-files),)
    @$(if $(strip $(clean-dirs)),echo $(MSG_CLEAN_DIRS))
# Remove created directories, and make sure we only remove existing
# directories, since recursive rmdir might help us a bit on the way.
ifeq ($(os),Windows)
    $(Q)$(if $(strip $(clean-dirs)),                        \
            $(RMDIR) $(strip $(subst /,\,$(clean-dirs))))
else
    $(Q)$(if $(strip $(clean-dirs)),                        \
        for directory in $(strip $(clean-dirs)); do     \
            if [ -d "$$directory" ]; then           \
                $(RMDIR) $$directory;           \
            fi                                      \
        done                                            \
    )
endif

# Rebuild the project.
.PHONY: rebuild
rebuild: clean all

# Debug the project in flash.
.PHONY: debug_flash
debug_flash: all
    $(GDB) -x "$(PRJ_PATH)/$(DEBUG_SCRIPT_FLASH)" -ex "reset" -readnow -se $(TARGET_FLASH)

# Debug the project in sram.
.PHONY: debug_sram
debug_sram: all
    $(GDB) -x "$(PRJ_PATH)/$(DEBUG_SCRIPT_SRAM)" -ex "reset" -readnow -se $(TARGET_SRAM)

.PHONY: objfiles
objfiles: $(obj-y)

# Create object files from C source files.
$(build-dir)%.o: %.c $(MAKEFILE_PATH) config.mk
    $(Q)test -d $(dir $@) || echo $(MSG_MKDIR)
ifeq ($(os),Windows)
    $(Q)test -d $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $@)) || mkdir $(subst /,\,$(dir $@))
else
    $(Q)test -d $(dir $@) || mkdir -p $(dir $@)
endif
    @echo $(MSG_COMPILING)
    $(Q)$(CC) $(c_flags) -c $< -o $@

# Create object files from C++ source files.
$(build-dir)%.o: %.cpp $(MAKEFILE_PATH) config.mk
    $(Q)test -d $(dir $@) || echo $(MSG_MKDIR)
ifeq ($(os),Windows)
    $(Q)test -d $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $@)) || mkdir $(subst /,\,$(dir $@))
else
    $(Q)test -d $(dir $@) || mkdir -p $(dir $@)
endif
    @echo $(MSG_COMPILING_CXX)
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(cxx_flags) -c $< -o $@

# Preprocess and assemble: create object files from assembler source files.
$(build-dir)%.o: %.S $(MAKEFILE_PATH) config.mk
    $(Q)test -d $(dir $@) || echo $(MSG_MKDIR)
ifeq ($(os),Windows)
    $(Q)test -d $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $@)) || mkdir $(subst /,\,$(dir $@))
else
    $(Q)test -d $(dir $@) || mkdir -p $(dir $@)
endif
    @echo $(MSG_ASSEMBLING)
    $(Q)$(CC) $(a_flags) -c $< -o $@

# Include all dependency files to add depedency to all header files in use.
include $(dep-files)

ifeq ($(target_type),lib)
# Archive object files into an archive
$(target): $(MAKEFILE_PATH) config.mk $(obj-y)
    @echo $(MSG_ARCHIVING)
    $(Q)$(AR) $(ar_flags) $@ $(obj-y)
    @echo $(MSG_SIZE)
    $(Q)$(SIZE) -Bxt $@
else
ifeq ($(target_type),elf)
# Link the object files into an ELF file. Also make sure the target is rebuilt
# if the common Makefile.sam.in or project config.mk is changed.
$(target): $(linker_script) $(MAKEFILE_PATH) config.mk $(obj-y)
    @echo $(MSG_LINKING)
    $(Q)$(LD) $(l_flags) $(obj-y) $(libflags-gnu-y) -o $@
    @echo $(MSG_SIZE)
    $(Q)$(SIZE) -Ax $@
    $(Q)$(SIZE) -Bx $@
endif
endif

# Create extended function listing from target output file.
%.lss: $(target)
    @echo $(MSG_EXTENDED_LISTING)
    $(Q)$(OBJDUMP) -h -S $< > $@

# Create symbol table from target output file.
%.sym: $(target)
    @echo $(MSG_SYMBOL_TABLE)
    $(Q)$(NM) -n $< > $@

# Create Intel HEX image from ELF output file.
%.hex: $(target)
    @echo $(MSG_IHEX_IMAGE)
    $(Q)$(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(flashflags-gnu-y)  $< $@

# Create binary image from ELF output file.
%.bin: $(target)
    @echo $(MSG_BINARY_IMAGE)
    $(Q)$(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

# Provide information about the detected host operating system.
.SECONDARY: info-os
info-os:
    @echo $(MSG_INFO)$(os) build host detected

# Build Doxygen generated documentation.
.PHONY: doc
doc:
    @echo $(MSG_GENERATING_DOC)
    $(Q)cd $(dir $(doccfg)) && $(DOCGEN) $(notdir $(doccfg))

# Clean Doxygen generated documentation.
.PHONY: cleandoc
cleandoc:
    @$(if $(wildcard $(docdir)),echo $(MSG_CLEAN_DOC))
    $(Q)$(if $(wildcard $(docdir)),$(RM) --recursive $(docdir))

# Rebuild the Doxygen generated documentation.
.PHONY: rebuilddoc
rebuilddoc: cleandoc doc
```

Comment: What does your compiler and linker command look like? (i.e. which compiler/linker flags are you using?

Comment: MMA8652.cpp is the same of Task.h and Task.cpp is the same as Main.cpp. Correct please. Btw I think that you have to post the list file with c++ non commented. If you use c++, some other code is put into .text section.

Comment: @Verax i've added my config.mk and Makefile. You can find the flags in Makefile.sam.in

Comment: Are you really gaining anything by dragging in C++ runtime support that you couldn't do with function pointers / fields in a task structure?

Answer (score 0):

According to my calculations, your `.text` segment is around 4k.

Many linker applications for embedded systems, have a command or configuration file.  The configuration file tells the starting addresses of segments and size.

You will need to find the configuration file and verify that the ROM section is at the correct address and has the correct capacity.

Comment: How did you calculate that? I've added the linker script (.ld) to the topic post which is created by atmel so i doubt that is the problem. I've checked the datasheet (page.31) and the start address of both flash and rom are correct

Comment: @ReinierHasper : Well he really did not calculate it - he read it in your question .text size = 0x102c.  You have perhaps not made it clear that that is the size of the "empty" code?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `-Os` instead of `-O3` in  `OPTIMIZATION` flag inside `config.mk`; you may also use `-flto -Os` both when compiling and when linking (for link-time optimizations)

Comment: alright i will try that out. I found this [link](http://www.embedded.com/design/mcus-processors-and-socs/4007134/Building-Bare-Metal-ARM-Systems-with-GNU-Part-4). They say its important to dont link the exceptions libraries because it can take up to around 50kb. i've added the flags to the cxx flags but unfortunately i dont see any results

Comment: I noticed that when i empty my Main.cpp everything is fine. But when i use the new operator it goes wrong and the size is 15k to big

Comment: `new` in itself should not be significantly large, but with only 16kb or RAM, dynamic memory allocation it is best avoided in any case.   You have made it very difficult however for any one to determine that as an issue since your example code does not use `new`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it! i've added the fno-rtti and fno-exceptions and overloaded the new, delete and destructor operator.  http://www.embedded.com/design/mcus-processors-and-socs/4007134/Building-Bare-Metal-ARM-Systems-with-GNU-Part-4.

Unfortunately i cant overload the static_cast operator used in Task.h->action_helper() . Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: The `static_cast` issue is an entirely different question, you should post it as such - this is not a discussion forum.  It has little or no overhead, though a `reinterpret_cast` would have zero overhead.  You could make arg a `Task*` and cast to an appropriate function-pointer type at the `xTaskCreate` call.  It is not entirely clear to me what making `Task::run_helper()` a friend of its own class is; it already has access to its own members.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

- fno-exceptions is a good way to start, if you don't use it.
- RTTI can also be switched off, but I think it's worth to keep. It's a really powerful feature with minimal cost.
- overloading new/delete is not necessary. If you never use it and disable exceptions, it can be optimized by LTO. You have to worry about it only if you allocate dynamically.
- overloading static_cast? It's "static" because it's compile time. No reason to overload it, I'm not sure if it's possible at all.
- try changing debug info generation settings (-g flags in gcc)
- optimize for size if possible. It makes debugging really hard.

Don't forget that all of your ASF sources are C, so setting up the C toolchain is also necessary.